# Neumann Theorem about finite unions of cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, math-history

Some time ago, I was told the following theorem, attributed to Neumann (I have no idea which one):

> If $G$ is an abelian group, and $G$ is the finite union $\bigcup_{i\in I} g_iH_i$ of cosets of subgroups $H_i\leq G$, then it is already the union of those $g_iH_i$ for which $H_i$ has finite index.

It was proved by inclusion-exclusion principle, and back then, I had an idea of an inductive proof. I think in both cases, there didn't seem to be any reason for it to fail if $G$ is nonabelian.

The question is: which Neumann is this theorem due to, and in what form? And if s/he did not prove it in the above form (or an obviously equivalent one) with $G$ nonabelian, who did? I would appreciate some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of research on groups *covered* by a finite set of proper subgroups. It all started with a seminal paper of [Bernhard Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Neumann), *Groups covered by finitely many cosets*, Publ. Math. Debrecen 3 (1954), 227-242, in which he proves that if a group is the union of a finite number of subgroups (or even cosets), you only have to take into account those subgroups having finite index. This implies that a group has a finite covering by subgroups if and only if it has a finite non-cyclic homomorphic image. See also [recent work of Mira Bhargava](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/MiraBhargava07.pdf), the mother of the brilliant number theorist Manjul Bhargava.

Comment: I think this is actually the reference I had in mind, but I could not find it.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to answer my question fully. Well, it would be best if I could actually look at the reference, but this is enough to satisfy my curiosity. :)